# Why might Social Security employee deductions from paycheck vary across pay periods?

Tags: united-states, calculation, salary, social-security, payroll-taxes

What percentage of salary deducts for an employee's Social Security contribution? And why will there be a difference in % deducted?

My salary statement for October and September 2015 has the same hours and same hourly pay, yet I see a difference in Social Security employee deductions.

My September salary statement shows 709.28 while October shows 318.68 for Social Security employee deduction. See attached September, October paychecks:

- [September paycheck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjMHx.png)
- [October paycheck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ubDA.png)

Answer (score 17):

Social Security tax only applies to the first $118,500 you earn in a year.
See the Social Security Administration's [website](https://www.ssa.gov/news/press/factsheets/colafacts2015.html) for more info.
You should see a 6.2% increase in after tax earnings now.

If you switch employers mid-year, they will start withholding social security again.

Comment: +1 but it is worth mentioning that _each_ employer (including self-employment) must withhold SS tax until the salary that _each_ employer ndividually is paying exceeds the limit., and then _that_ employer can stop SS tax withholding. Fortunately, the total excess withholding (on total wages in excess of $118,500) of Social Security tax gets credited as a payment of Federal _income_ tax, and thus reduces what needs to be sent in with Form 1040 next year, or gets refunded to the taxpayer if the taxpayer had overpaid Federal taxes.  These computations get done on the second page of Form 1040.